# C++ assert doesn't produce stack frame when I include the iostream header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop. Here is the program:

```
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    assert(1 == 2);
}
```

When I run in Debug Mode, the assert fails and I click "Retry". Then a breakpoint is triggered, but I cannot see `a` in the variable list, and there is no function `main()` in call stack.

However, if I delete `#include<iostream>`, everything will be OK. I will be able to see `a` in the variable list, and `main()` will show up in call stack.

What's the problem?

Comment: can it be a VS2013 bug?

Comment: Could you do something with a after assert? e.g. a+=0;

Comment: Maybe you have encountered: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination

Comment: `a` probably got optimised away, since it is not used.

Comment: I run in debug mode, optimization should not happened. And I have tried adding some code use "a" after the "assert", but the same thing happened.

Comment: In which variable list are you looking? 'auto', 'local' or 'watch'?

Comment: I have tried all the three variable list. It seems the stack frame is damaged if I include iostream.

Comment: When you are looking at the call stack; do you see an entry something like: "[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing...

Comment: Yes I do in both cases (with or without iostream). But I don't think that's a problem, since the exception happens in msvcr120d.dll. I think at least I should be able to see variable in the stack of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [instruct Visual Studio 2013 to load the symbols from the MS Symbol Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx). Then you get this stacktrace:

> >msvcr120d.dll!_NMSG_WRITE(int rterrnum) Line 226  C
>       msvcr120d.dll!abort() Line 62   C
>       msvcr120d.dll!_wassert(const wchar_t * expr, const wchar_t * filename, unsigned int lineno) Line 156    C
>       ConsoleApplication1.exe!main() Line 7   C++
>       [External Code]

When _NMSG_WRITE is selected of course I cannot see variable a, but when selecting main() I can see the variable a in the autos and locals pane.

BTW, you should also consider updating to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I feel surprised why it doesn't work when I include iostream and don't download those symbols.